# Legendre symbols always match?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

When I test these Legendre symbols on the primes that are $p\equiv 1\bmod 12$, they always seem to equal each other:
$$\left( \frac{-6+2\sqrt{-3}}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right)$$
Is this true, and is there a way to show this?

Comment: What definition of "Legendre symbol" are you using when the first argument is not an integer?

Comment: -3 is a quadratic residue when p is 1 mod 12, so I mean a square root of -3 mod p

Comment: But square roots come in $\pm$  pairs. How did you decide which to use?

Comment: Either one will give you the same value, since if you take the product of the two "conjugate" symbols you get (48/p)=(3/p)=1, so they're both +1 or -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that
$$\left( \frac{-6+2\sqrt{-3}}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right) = \left  (\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right)$$

I can prove the second equality.
$$2\sqrt{3}(3 + 2\sqrt{3}) = 3(1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$
Hence,
$$\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right)$$
since $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = 1$.

**Update:**

Will Jagy noticed that the proof of $\left( \frac{-6+2\sqrt{-3}}{p}\right)= \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right)  $ is reduced to calculating $\left(\frac{2\sqrt{-1}}{p}\right)$.
You can prove it like this:
$$2\sqrt{3}(-6 + 2\sqrt{-3}) = -6\sqrt{-1}(1 + \sqrt{-3})^2$$
Hence,
$$\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3} (-6+2\sqrt{-3})}{p}\right) =\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{p}\right) = 1 \cdot (-1)^{\frac{p^2 - 1  }{8}} \cdot (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{4}} = 1$$

Comment: I think you have it. The other expression has:  $$  - \sqrt{-3} (-6 + 2 \sqrt{-3}) = 6 + 6 \sqrt{-3}  = (3 + \sqrt{-3})^2  $$

Comment: Good. I could see my item could be written over  in more revealing way; but I had run out of energy.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great! :D

Answer (score 1):

There are some needed things:  you have $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$  There is a split $\pmod 8:$

When $p \equiv 5 \pmod 8,$  $-1$ is not a fourth power $\pmod p,$  also $(2|p) = -1$

When $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$  $-1$ is  a fourth power $\pmod p,$  also $(2|p) = 1$

Denis has shown that $\left(\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{p}\right)$

The other expression has:  $$  - \sqrt{-3} (-6 + 2 \sqrt{-3}) = 6 + 6 \sqrt{-3}  = (3 + \sqrt{-3})^2  $$
so that $\left(\frac{-6+2\sqrt{-3}}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-\sqrt{-3}}{p}\right)$

The question of the OP amounts to the conjecture that

$$  ? \; \; \left(\frac{-\sqrt{-3} \cdot 2 \sqrt{3}}{p}\right) \; \; = \; \; 1  \; \; ?$$  or

$$  ?  \; \;\left(\frac{-6\sqrt{-1} }{p}\right) \; \; = \; \; \left(\frac{2\sqrt{-1}}{p}\right)   \; \; = \; \; 1 \; \; ?$$

From the beginning of this answer, either $2$ and $ \sqrt{-1}$   are both residues or both  are nonresidues; in either case

$$ \left(\frac{2\sqrt{-1}}{p}\right)   \; \; = \; \; 1$$

Short version: with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$  we know that there is a $\sqrt{-1}.$  With that in hand we find

$$ (1 + \sqrt{-1})^2 = 2 \sqrt{-1}  $$
so that, indeed,

$$ \color{red}{ \left(\frac{2\sqrt{-1}}{p}\right)   \; \; = \; \; 1 }$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!